# how to get the value from the database based on the id

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, database

i have a dropdown list that display the data from the database. i need to make dynamic using jquery and ajax where it will hide some values based on the user input on another field.

my question is how to hide the required option based on the returning ID.

## views.py

```
def getSource(request):
    sources = Source.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'create_folder.html', {'sources':sources})
```

## create_folder.html

```
<div class="formSelect" id="mouresaleMasdarDiv">
    <select id="mouresaleMasdar" name="gender" required>
        <option value="">-- soource--</option>
        {% for source in sources %} 
            <option val="{{ source.source_name }}"> {{ source.source_name }} </option>  
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#mouresaleMasdar option[value="{{sources.get(pk = 1)}}"]').hide()
</script>
```

It gives an error  so how to make this value hidden based on the id.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add ID to options

```
<option data-id="{{ source.id }}" val="{{ source.source_name }}"> {{ source.source_name }} </option>
```

i am not sure how it is in jquery but you can do this with JavaScript

```
const selected = document.querySelector('option[data-id="1"]');
selected.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: i tried your option but did not work the required value to be hide is still showen

Comment: did you replace "1" with the id you want?

Comment: the id that i want is 1

Comment: are you sure that you have source with id = 1? because if you try this code separately you see it works

Comment: sorry my mistake it works now  but in my case i have 3 switch cases. your answer is delete the value from all the cases. where i want is to just in one case to delete it and to display it in other switch cases

Comment: I wrote the code according to the information you provide above, I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: yes thank i will mark your answer but if you can can help me with the switch case  i will appreciate your help

Comment: can you add that code? if no other special occasion you can use this  `switch (key) {
        case value_that_hidden:
            selected.style.display = 'none';
            break;

        case value_that_display:
            selected.style.display = 'block';
            break;

        default:
            something
            break;
    }`